# Determining whether a particular JDK Method typically has an intrinsic implementation

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Short of the reading the OpenJDK source code (which I'm not averse to) is there a reasonably comprehensive (or 'official') list of [intrinsic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) within the Hotspot JVM (say for Intel)?

For example, what's the quickest way to determine whether [`Math.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(double)) will generally be converted directly to a few native instructions wherever it is used?

Comment: Since it depends on the JVM implementations, you'll probably have to dive source code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant part of the OpenJDK source code states:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l581

*"Here are all the intrinsics known to the runtime and the CI."*

So I suppose that's comprehensive enough!

Comment: Here's the equivalent for JDK 9 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l677

Answer (score 7):

Java 9 [adds](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076112) the `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation, which was renamed to just [`@IntrinsicCandidate` in JDK 16](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138732). Methods annotated with that annotation will have an intrinsic defined for them on at least one platform (and this is even [checked during class loading](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/10d62fa2183c0ed252ad0a9a743ae6a7710f9a95/src/hotspot/share/runtime/globals.hpp#L1911-L1922)).

Unfortunately this annotation does not show up in the online javadoc, but I can still see it using my IDE (Eclipse), and I assume that other IDEs provide a similar mechanism, so that is a fast way to check:

[image: Picture of eclipse javadoc window]

Comment: One small (and probably obvious) correction: Methods annotated "@IntrinsicCandidate" *may* be intrinsified … or not. It depends on the JVM for a particular platform. That's one reason for the pure Java implementations of most such methods; not only do they simplify bootstrapping the JVM on a new platform, but, afterward, they allow piecemeal intrinsification from one release to the next, according to perceived need, utility, and the relevant JVM developers' enthusiasm-to-time ratios. Not all JVMs receive the same love as, say, the x64 ports.