# Unit test coverage on java.lang classes with JaCoCo

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to do to unit tests coverage on the `java.lang` classes with JaCoCo.

**Context: What works so far**

This is not really standard, but is quite straightforward to copy the sources that are provided in `OpenJDK-8-sources` (on Ubuntu) in `${sourceDirectory}` and the classes that are provided in rt.jar into `${project.build.outputDirectory}`, and then the JaCoCo maven plugin can see them and generate suitable output for some classes.

For example, I get some coverage with sources for `sun.reflect.ByteVectorFactory`.

But I can't get coverage for the classes in `java.lang`. When calling `Byte.toString()`, the function is not covered in the report and the `Byte.class` does not show up in the data produced by `classDumpDir`.

I had a look in the sources of JaCoCo to see if `java.lang` is explicitly ignored and I didn't find anything obvious so far, but I am not familiar at all with JaCoCo source code.

**Actual question**

What can be done to work around this limitation? I am thinking of the following possibilities:

- It is a hard limitation of Java and nothing can be done about it
- The exclusion of `java.lang` is hardcoded in JaCoCo because it is a system package name, but this can be changed

  - by setting some hidden option or environment variable
  - by overwriting some files in the classpath by providing a modified version of them
  - by changing the JaCoCo source code

**EDIT**

I seems I am not alone to try to do this kind of thing.

Mailing list thread:
https://groups.google.com/g/jacoco/c/_tuoA7DHA7E/m/BQj53OvXoUsJ

Pull request on GitHub:
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/49

Somewhere in the middle of this, someone mentions that

> In particular JDK classes which are used by the Agent
> itself can probably not be tracked.

So it may explain why some of the classes are not instrumented.

Comment: Try with inclbootstrapclasses and inclnolocationclasses (https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html)

Comment: Yes I had set these options.

Comment: also, some of method implementation can be replaced at runtime by JVM with native code. These are called [intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721545/determining-whether-a-particular-jdk-method-typically-has-an-intrinsic-implement).

Answer (score 0):

I did more tests and I see that

- java.lang.Byte does  not get coverage
- java.lang.ProcessBuilder gets coverage
- java.util.ArrayList does not get coverage
- java.util.Calendar gets coverage

So it seems that classes that are already loaded when the agent loads cannot be instrumented in this way.

I extracted all the classes in `rt.jar` and instrumented them with offline instrumentation, then replaced `rt.jar` with their instrumented versions and included the JaCoCo agent in the bootstrap class path (using -Xbootclasspath).

Doing, this, I get the following infinite recursion:

```
        ...
        at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.Offline.getRuntimeData(Offline.java:36)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.Offline.getProbes(Offline.java:60)
        at java.lang.System.$jacocoInit(System.java)
        at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.Offline.getRuntimeData(Offline.java:36)
```

It should be possible to catch the recursion to prevent this, but this will clearly require some modifications to JaCoCo source code, and it is therefore not currently possible to have these classes instrumented.